# Can RAD Studio 2007 to XE6 be installed from pure command line?

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-xe6

I am not sure if RAD Studio from 2007 to XE6 are using same type of installer to package.  As end user of RAD Studio, I always run Setup.exe in RAD Studio and perform the installation by selecting options from the wizard dialogs page by page.

Is there any options in RAD Studio installer that may perform the installation via command line only without GUI dialogs?

Comment: The first result I get for "delphi unattended install" is [this](http://delphisorcery.blogspot.nl/2011/07/unattended-delphi-installation-how.html), which seems like it should work. You may want to give it a try and write it up as your own answer with the exact steps you've taken. (I'd do so myself but I don't have a clean system that I want to install anything on to test.)

Comment: They use InstallAware software so check if their installer supports silent install.

Comment: What does the product installation guide say on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful links regarding silent Delphi installs, not really an answer but what I found doing my own research

http://delphisorcery.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/unattended-delphi-installation-how.html
Has some notes on some of the command line parameters - still need to supply the license however

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29900
This article indicates that silent installs are not possible (not sure of its age however)

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Installation_Notes_for_XE6
XE6 release notes, doesn't say anything about silent installs

https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64992
A post for silently installing Delphi XE

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/137195-codegear-rad-studio-unattended-install/
Another post about silent Delphi installing

Comment: I try with XE6: I tried installation XE6 with the command line, but it is a full installation at last:

`setup LANGUAGE=English USERNAME="" USERCOMPANY="" PERSON_DW32=TRUE PERSON_CPPB=FALSE key1=xxxx key2=xxxxxx key3=xxxxxx key4=xxxx INSTALL_FEATURE_RADCOREBCBW64=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_COREOSXW32=FALSE INSTALL_BDE=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_DATABASE=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_HELPFILES=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_IBX=FALSE INSTALL_INTERBASE=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_COREMOBILE=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_CORBA=FALSE`

Comment: Maybe those properties were introduced in earlier XE installers, but that will not work anymore, I've inspected the XE7 MSI installer and it just contains several miles of features and components that follows a king of ID enumeration (not readable names like "Feature_Corba"), so it's just a nightmare impossible to manually specify what features to install from the msi, at least if you don't know which is each one of them (and it could be done, but its a lot of work inspecting one by one). I resign to install it as normally.