# Installing Delphi via the command-line (i.e. non UI) for Docker image

Tags: docker, delphi

I am looking at converting our build machines to use Docker images, and although the Delphi compiler has a command line option, the actual installer itself does not seem to, and therefore requires a Windows user interface, meaning it can't be installer into Docker for Windows. Has anyone managed to build a Delphi compiler docker image?

Comment: I have to ask. Why install on docker under windows ?

Comment: This is for a build machine, the dcc32/64 compiler can be run from the command line, so having non-permanent machines should avoid a permanent VM (Or VMs) having to be provisioned.

Comment: When calling the installer from the command line via `setup LANGUAGE=English USERNAME="" USERCOMPANY="" PERSON_DW32=TRUE PERSON_CPPB=FALSE key1=xxxx key2=xxxxxx key3=xxxxxx key4=xxxx INSTALL_FEATURE_RADCOREBCBW64=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_COREOSXW32=FALSE INSTALL_BDE=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_DATABASE=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_HELPFILES=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_IBX=FALSE INSTALL_INTERBASE=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_COREMOBILE=FALSE INSTALL_FEATURE_CORBA=FALSE`, it still calls the 'visual installer'

Comment: @Mark Humphreys: Please insert a "/s" separated by a space character right behind the call to SETUP.EXE and in front of the "LANGUAGE=..." parameter. Please see [Setup Command Line Parameters](https://www.installaware.com/flashhelp/setupcommandlineparameters.htm) for more info. And please in the future add the comment to the content that your are referring to, in this case my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article [Unattended Delphi installation](https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2011/07/unattended-delphi-installation-how.html) on how to perform an unattended install of Delphi by using [command line parameters](https://www.installaware.com/flashhelp/setupcommandlineparameters.htm), meaning that the installation does not require any user input and does not show any GUI. Unfortunately you do not specify which version of Delphi you want to install. If I remember correctly Delphi starting with version 2007 uses [InstallAware](https://www.installaware.com/) as its installer. According to the question [Can RAD Studio 2007 to XE6 be installed from pure command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503884/can-rad-studio-2007-to-xe6-be-installed-from-pure-command-line) the instructions in the article are still valid for Delphi XE6 and possibly for later versions as well.